# Angular 2 incorporating MEAN stack issue

Tags: node.js, express, mean-stack

I am trying to attach a backend to my angular 2 application. I have a Server.js file that grabs my index.html but I get an error at my `System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err) });` in my index.html

**error**

```
SCRIPt5009: 'System' is undefined
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
 <base href="/">
 <title>LGR</title>
 <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="./app/css/lgr.css">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
 <!-- 1. Load libraries -->

 <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
 <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
 <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
 <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
 <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>


<!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
<script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
<script>
  System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err) }); <----ERROR HERE!
</script>

</head>
<!-- 3. Display the application -->
<body>
 <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
</body>
</html>
```

**server.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();
var path = require('path');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/LGR_db');

app.use('app', express.static(__dirname + "/app"));
app.use('node_modules', express.static(__dirname + "/node_modules"));



app.get('/', function (req, res) {
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../LGR', 'index.html'));
});


app.listen('3000', function () {
console.log("Server is running on localhost:3000");
});
```

I am pretty lost here and any help would be great. I guess I don't understand how to "define" system??

**edit: added folder structure**

[image]

**Network output**

[image]

Comment: Can you show the file structure of your project? It looks like it's not finding the systemjs.config.js file.

Comment: @Scrambo added folder structure

Comment: When you try to run the app, can you do me a favor and look at the network trace in the Developer tools? Does anything 404 while trying to load the webpage initially? I have a theory that either the `systemjs.config.js` or the `.ts`/`.js` files will 404.

Comment: I am not getting a response back from any of my node modules

Comment: @Bean0341 I created a bare bones sample app [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rqisdjg2pzexgwg/LGR.zip?dl=0).  Would you be willing to download and run `node server` on it.  The load up `http://localhost:3000`?  If you get anything other than an error message complaining about not finding `main.js` there is something on your system preventing it from loading local static files.  This works on my machine as is with only the message about `main.js`

Comment: @Dave V its working! I just transferred in all my components and everything is displaying! ok uhm... I dont know what was fixed tho... I want to give you the bounty, can you edit your answer below or does is suffice?

Comment: @Bean0341 I edited it, not sure if that's what it takes or not.  Never really been a part of the bounty thing LOL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say it's because you are sending the `index.html` file specifically, and doing a static serve for the stuff in `/app`.  If the `systemjs.config.js` file was in the `/app` folder and referenced in the `index.html` as `src='/app/systemjs.config.js'` it may work.

-- EDIT: Still not 100% sure what the issue is.  I did everything we discussed in it and nothing else.  Glad it working though!

Comment: I remember having some issues with `__dirname` in the past (it not being what I expected it to be).  Can you log that out (`console.log()`) and make sure that the full path then would be to the right location?  I remember having to play with express for a while to get it to serve the static files like I needed them to.

Comment: could you be more specific? I am not getting any logging output from console.log(__dirname)

Comment: If you put a line in `console.log(__dirname);` right before say the first `app.use()` you do not get anything?

Comment: console.log(__dirname);
app.use('/app', express.static(__dirname + "/app")); I am not getting anything in the console

Comment: I got the console to write, the __dirname is correct.

Comment: Are you getting any of the files you are serving statically (like the css file?) or are they all returning 404?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121196/discussion-between-bean0341-and-dave-v).